# Not able to run Flutter Project in Android Emulator or Android Physical Device

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, android-library

**I am using Android Studio in Mac. When I try to run my newly created sample flutter project in Android Emulator , I am getting below Error.**

Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/29.0.5/licenses

Warning: License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 not accepted.

Checking the license for package Android Emulator in /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/29.0.5/licenses

Warning: License for package Android Emulator not accepted.

Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/29.0.5/licenses

Warning: License for package Android SDK Tools not accepted.

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/29.0.5/licenses

Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.

Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/29.0.5/licenses

Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
  >    patcher;v4 SDK Patch Applier v4
  >    build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
  >    emulator Android Emulator
  >    tools Android SDK Tools
  >    platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  >   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/29.0.5
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

**When I open android module from flutter project like this Image(Open Android Module in Android Studio),**

[image]

**Then New Android Studio window opened with Android Module of this sample project. I am able to run this android module project into emulator without any problem.
I wonder why android studio is giving this error when I directly run from flutter project of same android module.**

Note : All license for all android SDK packages are accepted

Answer (score 2):

Android SDK path of my flutter was not defined.. Once I change my flutter android sdk path using below command

```
flutter config --android-sdk 'My SDK Path'
```

Everything works well.. Now I am able to run in android emulator.